# How to debug Javascript on old browsers

Tags: javascript

Forgive me if this has been asked elsewhere.  I was not able to find a good answer yet.  I have some Javascript code that works perfect in the latest release of Firefox.  However, there is some odd behavior on an older browser that is used on our site.  For reasons beyond my control, I need to support this hacked up version of a browser that is actually embedded into another piece of software.

I am stabbing in the dark as to the cause of the issues.  I see no error console and of course tools like Firebug are a pipe dream.  How do I effectively debug browser-specific issues?  The old guess-and-check method will cost way too much time.

Comment: What can you tell us about this browser?  Also, it may be sufficient to make sure your JS Code validates (JSLint).  IE will complain about things like extra commas in Object Declarations, etc, and yours may be doing similar things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) in IE6+ and older versions of FF/Opera/Webkit.  The most useful feature of Firebug Lite in my opinion is probably the logging capabilities (`console.log`).

Checking the JavaScript for syntax errors before you even load the page with a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) can save you some headaches.  As a last resort, the reliable `window.alert` is always there.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect Firebug Lite to even work..but it did..with a few hacks to this browser.  That will save me a ton of time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browser.

You may want to look at Firebug Lite for Firebug-like features in older and non-Mozilla browsers.

If the browser is weird enough that you really have to guess and check on the client side, I'd recommend writing a pretty good set of tests to run on every browser.

Answer (score 1):

good luck with alert()'s

but you can try :

1) IE8 has the developer tools, that works fine in compatibility mode.

2) Firebug lite http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable

3) charge more from your damn clients that wants the thing to work in IE6

Answer (score 0):

If you can make do with logging, my own logging library [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) works in every major browser released since 1999.